# Why EJB execution is moved between threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, jboss, ejb, websphere

This is a real case I want to share with you:

```
ejb1.methodA() calls ejb2.methodB()
```

Sometimes, ejb2.methodB is called on the same thread that ejb1.methodA was running. But sometimes, JBoss (or WebSphere AS) decides to delegate de execution to another thread.

The questions are:

1. How its named this behaviour?. Its a part of a standard?
2. Is there a way to disable this delegation in order to execute all the methods on the same thread?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have @Async there? Or maybe in xml descriptors.
They should run in a single thread otherwise.

Comment: Also, are these local or remote method calls?  Either Async or Remote annotations (or in XML) could trigger the work to run on a different thread.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes we hava a <remote>interface name</remote> tag on every bean (EJB2.x) on ejb-jar.xml. No Async tags.

Comment: If you have remote interface, then each call is a `network` call, so it goes to the ORB pool of theads, so it is very likely that it will use different thread. If you are running your whole app in single JVM and dont have remote clients, I'd suggest to replace remote interfaces with local ones, it will execute on same thread and improve your performance also.

Comment: Thank you, Also, Gas. Its almost funny because the most of times the calls run local and only a few are remote.

Comment: The ORB will try to optimize "remote" EJB invocations within the same server/JVM.   I believe this optimized remote intra-JVM invocation will happen on a single thread.   Though it is possible to end up making a call that the ORB doesn't optimize, that goes over the network interface and back into the same JVM, in which case you'll end up on a different thread in the pool like Gas mentioned.   Have seen this happen when using multiple [network interfaces](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/trun_multiplenic.html)... could that apply here?

Comment: A couple more notes:  why are you asking ?  Just curious or worried about performance? Or does your programming model depend on a single thread context or something like that?    Note that an local EJB intfs use pass-by-reference while remote use pass-by-value, so Gas' suggestion of switching to local intf would only make sense if this were a non-issue for your data flow.

Comment: Thank you Scott. Yes there is a reason ;-). In this case we think a combination of too old tecnologies used by the application (hibernate, jboss, jee, etc) are causing us an issue when moving the current transaction to another thread and an optimistic lock like exception is thrown. We have seen that when these excetions are thrown always happen when the EJB method call has been delegated to another thread. Probably a bug involving transaction propagation?.... Anyway I have seen this method call relocation a lot of times in the past and I was just curious about that.

Comment: You'd think that DB locking wouldn't be affected by whether you were on the same thread or not, assuming you were always in the same transaction.    Well, hopefully I've helped a bit.   My guess is it must be the ORB moving the call onto another thread (or not).   Not sure if there are other reasons besides the multiple network interfaces this could happen upon.